# Is there a way to NOT a criteria array in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column with known values. 5 are written in stone, and the odd one is new. I need to filter on the new (unknown) value. If I only had 2 known values, I could filter out Criteria1 & 2 by using ="<>"

Since we can't use Criteria3, 4, ...
Is there a way to use something like:

Criteria1:="<>"Array("Val1", "Val2", ...)

(clarification: I want to show everything NOT in the array.)

Thanks.

Comment: Not directly with an autofilter. You either need to build an array of the values you do want (by looping and ignoring the known values), or you can use an advanced filter instead.

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

[image]

We want to see everything **except** *Val1*,*Val2*, and *Val3*

Here is one approach:

```
Sub AllButThree()
   Dim N As Long, ary(), c As Collection
   Dim i As Long, a As String, v As String
   ary = Array("Val1", "Val2", "Val3")
   Set c = New Collection
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   On Error Resume Next
   For i = 2 To N
      v = Cells(i, 1).Value
      If v <> ary(0) And v <> ary(1) And v < ary(2) Then
         c.Add v, CStr(v)
      End If
   Next i

   On Error GoTo 0
   ReDim bry(1 To c.Count)
   For i = 1 To c.Count
      bry(i) = c.Item(i)
   Next i

   ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A" & N).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=(bry), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

It builds an array of what we want to see.

Comment: Sweet. Exactly what I need.

Thanks.