# Excel: Autofilter exceptions with more than two criteria

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

This is a question that sometimes arises (e.g.: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891223/autofilter-exceptions-with-more-than-two-criteria) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611170/is-there-a-way-to-not-a-criteria-array-in-excel-vba)) and has almost always been given solutions based on some looping (with `AutoFilter()` itself or arrays)

For some reason Excel developers limited `AutoFilter` custom array criteria functioning to a maximum of two, so the following would not work:

```
    filterNotCriteria = Array("<>A","<>B","<>C")

    someRange.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=filterNotCriteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

While I think it'd be really helpful to have this `AutoFilter()` functionality *fully* available as it is for its "not custom" counterpart

So, while awaiting for Excel developers to add it (or fix it, since it looks to me more like a bug), I'd start this question as a public survey (not sure if this is the appropriate way) on what could be the best VBA fix, both from the performance and usability point of view

And I'm adding the first answer to start the ball rolling

Comment: Revisited earlier favorite bookmark and posted a late solution to your `Autofilter` question using repetitive `Filter` function calls. BTW *Seems you melted declaration and array assignment to* `Dim filterNotCriteria = Array("<>A","<>B","<>C")` :-)

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was to stick to `AutoFilter()`, to benefit from its performance

Using some *reverse thought*, the steps would be:

- filter with corresponding NOT(criteria)

  so as to get what we don't need
- hide the rows we got and that we don't need
- leave with "wanted" rows

as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Function AutoFilterNot(rngToFilter As Range, fieldToFilterOn As Long, filterNotCriteria As Variant) As Range
    Dim notRng As Range ' helper range variable

    With rngToFilter ' reference wanted range to filter, headers row included
        .AutoFilter field:=fieldToFilterOn, Criteria1:=filterNotCriteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues ' filter on "not wanted" values
        If Application.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then ' if any filtered cell other than header row
            Set notRng = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' temporarily set 'myRng' to "not wanted" rows
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False ' remove filters and show all rows
            notRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True ' leave "wanted" rows only visible

            Set AutoFilterNot = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' get referenced range "wanted" rows

            .EntireRow.Hidden = False ' unhide all referenced range rows
        Else
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False ' remove filters
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

and that could be used in some "main" code as follows:

```
Dim filteredRng As Range

Set filteredRng = AutoFilterNot(Range("A1:C200"), 2, Array("B102", "A107"))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Approach integrating repetitive `Filter` function**

The idea is to define a `include` criteria array applying the `Filter` function negatively (i.e. via argument `False`) to exclude search items in array `dont` (containing all criteria you don't want to display).

```
Sub ExcludeThem()
' Purpose: exclude search terms "A","B" and "C" from AutoFilter display
' [0] temporary boundary delimiters needed (because of automatic wild card search by Filter function)
      Const delim$ = "."
' [1] define exclude criteria
      Dim dont
      dont = Array("A", "B", "C"): AddDelimiters dont, delim
' [2] define include items; consider dictionary keys instead to get only unique items :-)
      Dim include, rng As Range           ' change source range to your Needs (here A1:A10)
      Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10")    ' refers to sheet via CodeName, e.g. AutFlt or Sheet1
      include = Application.Transpose(rng.Value2): AddDelimiters include, delim
' [3] resize include items by subsequent filtering out dont items
      Dim i&
      For i = 0 To UBound(dont)
          include = Filter(include, dont(i), False, vbTextCompare)
      Next i
' [4] clear remaining include items from temporary delimiters
      RemoveDelimiters include, delim
' [5] Execute AutoFilter, cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter
      rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=include, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

**Help procedures**

```
Sub AddDelimiters(ByRef arr, Optional ByVal delim$ = ".")
' Purpose: add boundary delimiters to array items
  Dim i&
  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
      arr(i) = delim & arr(i) & delim
  Next i
End Sub

Sub RemoveDelimiters(ByRef arr, Optional ByVal delim$ = ".")
' Purpose: remove boundary delimiters from array items
  Dim i&
  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
      arr(i) = Replace(arr(i), delim, vbNullString)
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad you measured yourself against this issue (first one after me!). My undesrtanding is your approach could be slowed down in case of _many_ rows, since you are processing the whole array twice for adding and removing delimeters and then again as many times as `dont` items: have you tested it on some 10K (or more) database?

Comment: Thx for feed back; depends on your actual data structure and 1) if you are in need of **exact findings** - if not, you can omit adding/deleting of delimiters completely. 2) Are there only **unique** values, if not try my suggestion to reduce the include array via Dictionary. My main intention was to demonstrate an easy approach that *does* use `Autofilter` instead of a work around. As for the performance point of view I didn't measure it against your solution, plz show some example data in your answer with hints to points 1) and 2). - @DisplayName

Comment: Well, my approach does use `Autofilter`, too… While as for performance issue I asked the question, too....: let's wait for the first to test both, whoever he/she wil be...

Comment: :-) Sorry, didn't refer to your approach, but to numerous other solutions/ work arounds avoiding `Autofilter`. Just didn't test it yet.… *Encore:* Do you need to exclude exact findings only or also partial findings? *(BTW I'm always interested in interesting or innovative questions that's why I voted it up in September).* - @DisplayName

Comment: Your approach seems to beat mine in the range from 20K (0,05 secs) to 65K (0,17 secs) by roughly 0,02:0,04 secs, wheras to my surprise I seem to gain clearly in ranges >70K. Further notes: I'm using Excel 2019 (test data included 10% of each exclusion string in steps of 10). - For the sake of the art only: are you interested in a further (slower) approach using a help column, but showing rather unknown features of `Application.Match`? - could edit it as appendix… @DisplayName