# Filtering with VBA when a filter criteria may not always appear

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get VBA to filter a column such that shows all results that contain 4 potential results.

I have managed to get it to achieve success when filtering 3 phrases (as visible in my code below). However the 4th option is not always in the data, some of the times I run this report it will not be in the column. Currently when I add this option to my code it suddenly shows no results at all. Any tips or advice would be great.

```
Workbooks("Stock Data.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Activate
Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Apple", "Banana", "Raspberry", "chocolate")
```

It's annoying that It works fine for my original 3 choices and just because the fourth option 'chocolate' isn't in the data it won't work at all.

If i remove the 'chocolate' option then I get the exact results I want but I don't want to have to change it every time I get data.

Comment: Have you attempted to fillter with all arguments, e.g., declaring the full range to filter, then choosing which field to filter?  I am wondering if the filtered range isn't all of your contiguous data.

Comment: Also, is the word you want 'Chocolate' or 'chocolate'?  Those are different.

Comment: Hi Cyril, I changed the phrases due to the potential sensitivity of the data so just use 'chocolate' as an example. the filter works perfectly for the first 3 phrases for all my data so I believe everything is being picked up

Comment: maybe you could benefit from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52246299/excel-autofilter-exceptions-with-more-than-two-criteria)

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn **not** to use `Activate`. and add `, Operator:=xlFilterValues`

```
Workbooks("Stock Data.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Apple", "Banana", "Raspberry", "chocolate"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I would use `ThisWorkbook` if the macro is in `Workbooks("Stock Data.xlsm")`

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("Apple", "Banana", "Raspberry", "chocolate"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```